# Page numbering after continuous section break won't restart in 1

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

I have a document with several sections. I want to introduce a new numbering after specific continuous section breaks starting at 1, but it won't work. So say that I am at page 34 and I want to introduce a section break between page 34 and 35, and restart what was before page 35, now as page 1. Well, this doesn't work and starts always at 2. The problem persists, independently of checking or unchecking the 'first different page' option. The problem also happens when, for instance, if instead of wanting to start what was before 35, now I want it to be page 36. The same problem occurs, and instead of 36, appears as 37.

Comment: What about the Link to Previous setting? Have you cleared it?

Comment: @sumusa The link to previous setting has nothing to do with the formatting of page numbers. It can change whether or not they appear, but not the numbering.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Next-Page section break, not a continuous one.

Here are three references on Sections and Section Breaks.

- [Working with Sections](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Formatting/WorkWithSections.htm) by MVP Dave Rado
- [Sections, Headers & Footers in Microsoft Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm) (my page)
- [Numbering Front Matter](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill

Comment: Took me about 30 minutes to find your answer; thank you for posting this! Words is such a complex beast...

Comment: It is quite complex when you want to do more than a simple letter or memo. By design it is easy to use if you only want to do simple things. If you want more, there are lots of tools available in Word, but you need to learn them. Here is a link about some of Word's conventions/expectations/methods https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/BasicConceptsWord.htm